# How to register an Active X .ocx library in Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, activex, delphi-xe4

I am trying to register an Active X .ocx Library in a Delphi program i have tried the following code with out success no errors and the program runs through all of the code but when it has finished the Active X Library hasn't been registered. What am i doing wrong ?

```
    procedure RegisterOCX;
    type
      TRegFunc = function : HResult; stdcall;

    var
      ARegFunc : TRegFunc;
      aHandle  : THandle;
      ocxPath,AppPath  : string;
      begin
      GetDir(0, AppPath);
       try
        ocxPath := AppPath + '\VOIP.ocx';
        aHandle := LoadLibrary(PChar(ocxPath));
        if aHandle <> 0 then
        begin
          ARegFunc := GetProcAddress(aHandle,'DllRegisterServer');
          if Assigned(ARegFunc) then
          begin
            ExecAndWait('regsvr32','/s ' + ocxPath);
          end;
            FreeLibrary(aHandle);

        end;
       except
         ShowMessage('Unable to register ');
        end; 
      end;

    function ExecAndWait(const ExecuteFile, ParamString : string): boolean;
    var
      SEInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
      ExitCode: DWORD;
    begin
      FillChar(SEInfo, SizeOf(SEInfo), 0);
      SEInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
      with SEInfo do begin
      fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
      Wnd := Application.Handle;
      lpFile := PChar(ExecuteFile);
      lpParameters := PChar(ParamString);
      nShow := SW_HIDE;
    end;
    if ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo) then
    begin
      repeat
       Application.ProcessMessages;
       GetExitCodeProcess(SEInfo.hProcess, ExitCode);
      until (ExitCode <> STILL_ACTIVE) or Application.Terminated;
       Result:=True;
    end
    else Result:=False;
  end;
```

Comment: Why do you go so far as to load `DllRegisterServer` and then not run it?! That `/s` flag makes debugging hard. Remove it. You do have admin rights don't you?

Comment: The `regsvr32.exe` process require elevation. So check if you process had the proper rights. also change the nShow parameter from `SW_HIDE` to `SW_SHOW` and remove the `/s` parameter for now, to display the messages of the `regsvr32`. Also be sure to add double quotes to the path of the ocx file to register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making life hard for yourself by using regsvr32. You've gone 99% of the way to doing without. Instead of calling regsvr32, just call `DllRegisterServer`. After all, that's all that regsvr32 is going to do!

Your code becomes:

```
if Assigned(ARegFunc) then
  OleCheck(ARegFunc());
```

You can then remove `ExecAndWait` altogether. Which is nice because it saves me discussing the busy loop, and the leaked handle!

It would make sense to me to rename the variable that you called `ARegFunc` as `DllRegisterServer`. So the code might then look like this:

```
aHandle := LoadLibrary(PChar(ocxPath));
if aHandle = 0 then
  RaiseLastWin32Error;
try
  DllRegisterServer := GetProcAddress(aHandle,'DllRegisterServer');
  if Assigned(DllRegisterServer) then
    OleCheck(DllRegisterServer());
finally
  FreeLibrary(aHandle);
end;
```

The most likely failure mode for a call to `DllRegisterServer` will be a failure to run your registration code elevated.

As an aside, `LoadLibrary` returns `HMODULE` rather than `THandle`.

Comment: What comes after `if Assigned(ARegFunc) then`                             
  `OleCheck(ARegFunc());` or is that It ?

Comment: Er, that's it. At that point you have registered the server. Obviously you throw in a call to `FreeLibrary`. Which should appear in a try/finally to guard against exceptions.